# LINQ converting anaonymous list to strongly type with date splits in groupBY

Tags: linq

I am trying to group together daily logs into months in a linq query from a dbset, getting above or below a percentage of allowed usage.

The dbset is on

```
public partial class DailyUsageForYear
{
    public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> NumUsers { get; set; }
    public int AllowedUsageCount { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid SupplierID { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying the to get a list of objects like

```
public class UsageDisplay
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public int NumUsers { get; set; }
    public int AllowedUsageCount { get; set; }
    public Guid ApplicationID { get; set; }
}
```

However the select at the end of my statement does not seem to understand the field names, can anyone tell me please, what am I missing about the linq syntax?

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<DailyUsageForYear>();
    predicate = predicate.And (x => x.NumUsers > (x.AllowedUsageCount *    (DropPercentage/100)));
if (supplier != null)
{
    Guid supplierGuid = new Guid (supplier.ToString());
    predicate = predicate.And (x => x.SupplierID == supplierGuid);
}
if (Direction == 0)
    predicate = predicate.And (x => x.NumUsers < (x.AllowedUsageCount * (Percentage/100)));
else
    predicate = predicate.And (x => x.NumUsers > (x.AllowedUsageCount * (Percentage/100)));
usageDetailModel.usage = db.DailyUsageForYears.**Where**(predicate)
    .**GroupBy**(x => new { x.DateAdded.Year, x.DateAdded.Month, x.Application, x.NumUsers, x.SeatCount, x.LicenceID })
    .**Select**(u => new UsageDisplay() { Year = u.DateAdded.Year, Month = u.DateAdded.Month, Application = u.Application, NumUsers = u.NumUsers, SeatCount = u.SeatCount, ApplicationId = u.ApplicationID });
```

Comment: Drop the `.DateAdded` that appears twice in your `Select`. The anonymous object only picks up the last property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside last select `u` is not `DailyUsageForYear` its groupping object with `Key` field, so try change your select like this

```
.Select(u => new UsageDisplay() { 
                    Year = u.Key.Year, 
                    Month = u.Key.Month, 
                    Application = u.Key.Application, 
                    NumUsers = u.Key.NumUsers, 
                    SeatCount = u.Key.SeatCount, 
                    ApplicationId = u.Key.ApplicationID 
                });
```

also in

```
.GroupBy(x => new { 
        x.DateAdded.Year, 
        x.DateAdded.Month, 
        x.Application,
        x.NumUsers, 
        x.SeatCount, 
        x.LicenceID })
```

i think you need `x.ApplicationId` instead of `x.LicenceID`